# Are there any movies or series involving someone with ADHD?

Tags: cinema-history

Aside from How I Met Your Mother, The Simpsons or Finding Nemo, if that counts, are there any movies or TV series involving someone explicitly stated or highly believed to have ADHD? I can't seem to find any on Google.

There are movies or TV series about schizophrenia such as A Beautiful Mind, bipolar such as Silver Linings Playbook and [then there's this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_films_featuring_mental_disorders), but I can't seem to find any for ADHD.

---

Of course there are [endless speculations](https://www.reddit.com/r/ADHD/comments/1wjsfu/movies_with_adhd_characters/) on forums everywhere, but these are speculations likely from not properly educated people (e.g. not psychologists).

An example if this question was asking about OCD or Asperger's would be Sheldon Cooper from The Big Bang Theory. The show or creators have never stated any diagnosis, but people highly believe such. Sheldon even has his own [article on Psychology Today](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/aspergers-diary/200904/sheldony-or-aspergery-the-big-bang-theory).

Comment: For OCD the more obvious example would have been Adrian Monk from Monk (or his brother who only appeared in a few episodes). And Sheldon is perfectly healthy, *his mother had him tested* ;)

Comment: Considering [almost half](http://adultaddstrengths.com/2011/01/12/adhd-and-crime-ignore-now-jail-later-15-clinical-studies/) of inmates have ADHD, chances are pretty big that you'll find them in a villain.

Comment: Here you go: http://www.imdb.com/search/title?plot=ADHD&title_type=feature,tv_movie,tv_series,mini_series,short&sort=num_votes,desc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed you asked this question on the cognitive science stackexchange as well, so I'll try to not include the same information as you received there.

This is a tough one to answer, because as you probably would have guessed, it's not often stated when a character suffers from ADHD. There are a lot of speculations, but let's look at the characters that are confirmed to have ADHD.

Percy Jackson is a character that struggles with ADHD and dyslexia. This was actually the reason [Chris Columbus](http://io9.gizmodo.com/5470194/why-percy-jacksons-dyslexia-convinced-chris-columbus-to-direct) wanted to direct the movie, as his daughter suffered from dyslexia. Chris realised that his daughter could relate to Percy very well en feel empowered by him.

Another movie I found is [Sister](http://www.parents.com/blogs/parents-perspective/2014/05/02/news/powerful-new-movie-sister-raises-awareness-for-kids-with-adhd-and-questions-about-dealing-with-the-disorder/), which is about the relationship between Billy Presser and his adopted kid sister. The sister suffers from ADHD and other disorders. The Movie is loosely based on the director's life and meant to raise awareness surrounding ADHD and mental illness.

In the movie Accepted, there is also a character that has ADD. I have not seen this movie and am not sure how big his part in the movie is.

Answer (score 2):

There's most certainly [at least 10 of them](http://www.additudemag.com/slideshow/219/slide-1.html)

If you're looking for "first occurrence", possibly Maria von Trapp from [*The Sound Of Music* (1965)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0059742/).

Comment: Was Marian von Trapp revealed to have ADHD in director interviews or something? Or did the notion just come from people watching the film and categorizing her behavior?

Comment: Maria von Trapp was a real person, that movie was based on a book written by her.  And if you google her and ADHD, you'll get plenty of hits.